# Run javascript on specific URL load

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to run javascript on specific URL load, below is my code. It only shows an alert on the home page, not on the URL I have a condition on i.e. **https://www.example.com/cart** it gives an alert message on the home page only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currURL = window.location.href;

   function codeAddress() {

     if (currURL = 'https://www.example.com/cart'){
            alert('We are not shipping to countries that are not listed in shipping country!');
     }
    }
  window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```js
if (currURL = 'https://www.example.com')
```

should be

```js
if (currURL === 'https://www.example.com')
```

Remember that,

1. `=` is assignment, not comparison.
2. `==` is comparison without type check.

   ```js
   1 == '1'  // true
   1 == 1    // true
   ```
3. `===` is comparison with type check.

   ```js
   1 == '1'  // false
   1 == 1    // true
   ```

Comment: I was looking at this code trying to find the problem for 5 minutes and still didn't realize where was the mistake bruuh